# Stock dialer app buttons

Tags: android

I want to make an activity that looks like this, more specifically I want to copy the look of the dialer buttons.

Can I find the xml styles for these buttons somewhere online? Or even better, a library?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Use an APK decompiler to retrieve the resources. So first find the APK on your system.

Comment: @RvdK That's part of AOSP Android. OP can just look up the code.

Comment: @RaghavSood indeed, my mistake :) You can easily look into the AOSP source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, here's the XML you need: [Git: Android Open Source Project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/jb-mr2.0-release/res/layout/dialpad.xml)

And you can find the resources used on the digits when digging in the XML:

```
<TableRow
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1">
    <com.android.dialer.dialpad.DialpadImageButton
        android:id="@+id/one" style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_1_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_one" />
    <com.android.dialer.dialpad.DialpadImageButton
        android:id="@+id/two" style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_2_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_two" />
    <com.android.dialer.dialpad.DialpadImageButton
        android:id="@+id/three" style="@style/DialtactsDialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_3_wht"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_three" />
</TableRow>
```